# Make Package Manager download Nuget packages to a specific folder

Tags: .net, directory, nuget

I wanted the Nuget Package Manager in Visual Studio to download packages to a specific folder inside the solution, instead of putting them in the user's subfolder. I found this piece of code that I put in `Shared.msbuild`:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <PackageDirectory>$(SolutionDir)\packages</PackageDirectory>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work well. When I build the solution, I get errors in the Output terminal about missing packages.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is there a reason you want this behavior? Which version of .NET are you using?

Comment: I'm migrating this application from .net framework 4.8 to .net6/.net standard2.0. I want this behavior because some nuget packages are declared in Shared.msbuild and don't seem to get restored to the solution folder but instead to the user folder and when I'm building the solution I get nuget package errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a property globalPackagesFolder in the nuget.config to define a new folder where the packages can be downloaded. This can be a relative path as well. To put the packages in a solution, you may want to create a solution specific nuget.config and clear the user level config properties and define new ones relevant to your solution.

```html
<config>
    <add key="globalPackagesFolder" value="c:\packages" />
</config>
```

Here are some docs to help you:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file#config-section
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders

Comment: Can I define the download folder in the solution-specific nuget.config but then define the solution's nuget repo (the source to download packages from) in a separate file?

Comment: Unfortunately, defining the folder in Nuget.config doesn't help. Packages are not downloaded into the specified folder.